# Post-process/filter all textilizable fields in Redmine via plugin?

Tags: redmine, monkeypatching, redmine-plugins, textile

I am attempting to write a Redmine plugin which further filters textilizable fields (issue description, updates, wiki content, etc.).

I've leafed around the plugin documentation but did not really find a good place to start.  The view hooks seem to allow you to inject content at pre-defined injection points.  Nothing really stood out toward creating a filter for textilizable content.

The most straightforward way is to hack the code in `application_helper.rb` and create your own filter function along the same lines of the `:parse_inline_attachments, :parse_wiki_links, :parse_redmine_links`.  However, I do not see a good way of inserting that in a plugin without monkey patching the entirety of `textilizable(*args)`.

Am I missing something obvious here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way, here: http://www.redmine.org/boards/3/topics/33949

This board topic mentions the caveats associated with view hooks (mentioned above) and offers a workaround or two that lets you change content by overriding views.